# Add new line into Eclipse's Text control field

Tags: java, eclipse, file, swt

How can I add new line into Eclipse's Text control field?

I need to open file and read it.

And it works except the part that all of the content is in one single line.

Tried with:

```
                String sCurrentLine;

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

                while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

                    text.setText( text.getText() + sCurrentLine + "\r\n");


                }
```

... but still is all in one single line......

Pls help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the SWT `Text` control you must create it with the `SWT.MULTI` style to support multiple lines.

```
text = new Text(parentComposite, SWT.MULTI);
```

Comment: It is multi, it's defined as: text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.SEARCH | SWT.CANCEL | SWT.MULTI | SWT.FILL);

Comment: SWT.FILL is not valid for Text and has the same value as SWT.SINGLE which will cause confusion. I'm not sure what including SWT.SEARCH will do.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, it works now with definition of: text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.MULTI);